# This loop appears to not be constant, but I don't know why

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to test a random number generator for my test game I've been working on. It is presently set to always perform the action regardless of the generated number and simply say "cheeeeeeeese" on the screen, but my issue is that it flashes that word upon input by mouse or arrow keys but wont stick. I do not understand why it flashes and only when i'm inputting.

```
import pygame, sys, random
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

BLACK =          (  0,   0,   0)
ABINO =          ( 34,  45, 102)
PINDLER =        (255, 123,  90)
MEXON =          (200, 190, 220)
WHITE =          (255, 255, 255)

size = [700, 500]
D = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
L = pygame.draw.aaline
R = pygame.draw.rect
G = random.randrange(1, 10)

pygame.display.set_caption("Tester of Mester")
myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 15)
T = myfont.render
M1S = "RULES:"
M2S = "1. To start, press each arrow key in a random sequence"
M2F = " for roughly one second."
M3S = "2. To win, re-merge the four men on the crossmark."
M4S = "3. Complete before the running man leaves the screen."
M5S = "4. Mouse movement is illegal and causes a severe time penalty."
L1 = T(M1S, 1, (255, 255, 0))
L2 = T(M2S, 1, (255, 255, 0))
L2C = T(M2F, 1, (255, 255, 0))
L3 = T(M3S, 1, (255, 255, 0))
L4 = T(M4S, 1, (255, 255, 0))
L5 = T(M5S, 1, (255, 255, 0))
B = D.blit
Fx = 10
Fy = 10
L6 = T("cheeeeeeeeese", 1, (255, 255, 0))

def MOLINE1(D, x, y):
    pygame.draw.ellipse(D, BLACK, [1 + x, y, 10, 10], 0)

    pygame.draw.line(D, BLACK, [5 + x, 17 + y], [10 + x, 27 + y], 2)
    pygame.draw.line(D, BLACK, [5 + x, 17 + y], [x, 27 + y], 2)

    pygame.draw.line(D, PINDLER, [5 + x, 17 + y], [5 + x, 7 + y], 2)

    pygame.draw.line(D, PINDLER, [5 + x, 7 + y], [9 + x, 17 + y], 2)
    pygame.draw.line(D, PINDLER, [5 + x, 7 + y], [1 + x, 17 + y], 2)

def MOLINE2(D, x, y):
    pygame.draw.ellipse(D, BLACK, [1 + x, y, 10, 10], 0)

    pygame.draw.line(D, BLACK, [5 + x, 17 + y], [10 + x, 27 + y], 2)
    pygame.draw.line(D, BLACK, [5 + x, 17 + y], [x, 27 + y], 2)

    pygame.draw.line(D, PINDLER, [5 + x, 17 + y], [5 + x, 7 + y], 2)

    pygame.draw.line(D, PINDLER, [5 + x, 7 + y], [9 + x, 17 + y], 2)
    pygame.draw.line(D, PINDLER, [5 + x, 7 + y], [1 + x, 17 + y], 2)

def MOLINE3(D, x, y):
    pygame.draw.ellipse(D, BLACK, [1 + x, y, 10, 10], 0)

    pygame.draw.line(D, BLACK, [5 + x, 17 + y], [10 + x, 27 + y], 2)
    pygame.draw.line(D, BLACK, [5 + x, 17 + y], [x, 27 + y], 2)

    pygame.draw.line(D, PINDLER, [5 + x, 17 + y], [5 + x, 7 + y], 2)

    pygame.draw.line(D, PINDLER, [5 + x, 7 + y], [9 + x, 17 + y], 2)
    pygame.draw.line(D, PINDLER, [5 + x, 7 + y], [1 + x, 17 + y], 2)

def MOLINE4(D, x, y):
    pygame.draw.ellipse(D, BLACK, [1 + x, y, 10, 10], 0)

    pygame.draw.line(D, BLACK, [5 + x, 17 + y], [10 + x, 27 + y], 2)
    pygame.draw.line(D, BLACK, [5 + x, 17 + y], [x, 27 + y], 2)

    pygame.draw.line(D, PINDLER, [5 + x, 17 + y], [5 + x, 7 + y], 2)

    pygame.draw.line(D, PINDLER, [5 + x, 7 + y], [9 + x, 17 + y], 2)
    pygame.draw.line(D, PINDLER, [5 + x, 7 + y], [1 + x, 17 + y], 2)

def MOLINE5(D, x, y):
    pygame.draw.ellipse(D, BLACK, [1 + x, y, 10, 10], 0)

    pygame.draw.line(D, BLACK, [5 + x, 17 + y], [10 + x, 27 + y], 2)
    pygame.draw.line(D, BLACK, [5 + x, 17 + y], [x, 27 + y], 2)

    pygame.draw.line(D, PINDLER, [5 + x, 17 + y], [5 + x, 7 + y], 2)

    pygame.draw.line(D, PINDLER, [5 + x, 7 + y], [9 + x, 17 + y], 2)
    pygame.draw.line(D, PINDLER, [5 + x, 7 + y], [1 + x, 17 + y], 2)

def FINISH(D, x, y):
    R(D, BLACK, ( 4, 42, 6, 6))
    R(D, WHITE, (10, 42, 6, 6))
    R(D, BLACK, (16, 42, 6, 6))
    R(D, WHITE, (22, 42, 6, 6))
    R(D, BLACK, (28, 42, 6, 6))
    R(D, WHITE, (34, 42, 6, 6))

    R(D, WHITE, ( 4, 48, 6, 6))
    R(D, BLACK, (10, 48, 6, 6))
    R(D, WHITE, (16, 48, 6, 6))
    R(D, BLACK, (22, 48, 6, 6))
    R(D, WHITE, (28, 48, 6, 6))
    R(D, BLACK, (34, 48, 6, 6))

    R(D, BLACK, ( 4, 54, 6, 6))
    R(D, WHITE, (10, 54, 6, 6))
    R(D, BLACK, (16, 54, 6, 6))
    R(D, WHITE, (22, 54, 6, 6))
    R(D, BLACK, (28, 54, 6, 6))
    R(D, WHITE, (34, 54, 6, 6))

x_speed = 0
y_speed = 0

x2_speed = 0
y2_speed = 0

x3_speed = 0
y3_speed = 0

x4_speed = 0
y4_speed = 0

x_coord = 300
y_coord = 300

x2_coord = 300
y2_coord = 300

x3_coord = 300
y3_coord = 300

x4_coord = 300
y4_coord = 300

X5_coord = 30
Y5_coord = 10

direction = 'right'

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x_speed =- 3
                x2_speed = 3
                y3_speed =- 3
                y4_speed = 3
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_speed = 3
                x2_speed =- 3
                y3_speed = 3
                y4_speed =- 3
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                y_speed =- 3
                y2_speed = 3
                x3_speed =- 3
                x4_speed = 3
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y_speed = 3
                y2_speed =- 3
                x3_speed = 3
                x4_speed =- 3

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x_speed=0
                x2_speed=0
                y3_speed=0
                y4_speed=0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_speed=0
                x2_speed=0
                y3_speed=0
                y4_speed=0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                y_speed=0
                y2_speed=0
                x3_speed=0
                x4_speed=0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y_speed=0
                y2_speed=0
                x3_speed=0
                x4_speed=0

        elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            x_coord = 300
            y_coord = 300
            x2_coord = 300
            y2_coord = 300
            x3_coord = 300
            y3_coord = 300
            x4_coord = 300
            y4_coord = 300
            X5_coord = 30
            Y5_coord = 10
            direction = 'right'

        elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            X5_coord = 30
            Y5_coord = 10
            direction = 'right'

        if direction == 'right':
            X5_coord += 10
            if X5_coord == 670:
                direction = 'down'
        elif direction == 'down':
            Y5_coord += 10
            if Y5_coord == 460:
                direction = 'left'
        elif direction == 'left':
            X5_coord -= 10
            if X5_coord == 10:
                direction = 'up'
        elif direction == 'up':
            Y5_coord -= 10
            if Y5_coord == 10:
                direction = 'right'

        if G >= 0:
            B(L6, (80, 150))


        pygame.display.update()


    x_coord = x_coord + x_speed
    y_coord = y_coord + y_speed

    x2_coord = x2_coord + x2_speed
    y2_coord = y2_coord + y2_speed

    x3_coord = x3_coord + x3_speed
    y3_coord = y3_coord + y3_speed

    x4_coord = x4_coord + x4_speed
    y4_coord = y4_coord + y4_speed

    D.fill(MEXON)

    B(L1, (47, 45))
    B(L2, (47, 60))
    B(L2C, (65, 75))
    B(L3, (47, 90))
    B(L4, (47, 105))
    B(L5, (47, 120))

    L(D, PINDLER, (40, 5), (695, 5), 10)
    L(D, PINDLER, (3, 42), (3, 495), 10)
    L(D, PINDLER, (3, 495), (695, 495), 10)
    L(D, PINDLER, (695, 495), (695, 5), 10)

    L(D, PINDLER, (3, 41), (658, 42), 10)
    L(D, PINDLER, (40, 5), (40, 458), 10)
    L(D, PINDLER, (40, 458), (658, 458), 10)
    L(D, PINDLER, (658, 458), (658, 42), 10)

    FINISH(D, Fx, Fy)

    MOLINE1(D, x_coord, y_coord)

    MOLINE2(D, x2_coord, y2_coord)

    MOLINE3(D, x3_coord, y3_coord)

    MOLINE4(D, x4_coord, y4_coord)

    MOLINE5(D, X5_coord, Y5_coord)

    pygame.draw.line(D, PINDLER, (303, 302), (307, 306), 1)
    pygame.draw.line(D, PINDLER, (307, 302), (303, 306), 1)






    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: And only updating your display in the event  loop has nothing to do with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You blit your text "cheeeeeeeese" (variable `L6` in your program) onto the display surface `D`, update it (call `pygame.display.update()`), and right after that, you fill the **whole** surface by calling `D.fill(MEXON)`.

The result: **every time** an event occurs the text flashes up short,  because you "clear" the screen by calling pygames `fill()` function immediately after drawing the text.

What you could change to fix the problem:

1. Delete the `pygame.display.update()` line in your event loop. 
   You don’t need to do this because you flip (update) the display very time in your main game loop (`pygame.display.flip()`).
2. Write the code line

   ```
   if G >= 0:
       B(L6, (80, 150))
   ```

   *after* you call the `D.fill(MEXON)` method. 
    This should fix your flashing problem.